# SXA & Language fallback in list components

Tags: sxa, language-fallback

I have a website with SXA (1.7.1) and language fallback setup up. It all works fine for regular components (eg. carousel or a custom component made by us) but lists (eg. Link List) won't pick up fallback items.

So the problem is as follows:

1. There is a Link List component on the page
2. There is datasource with list of links in the Data section
3. The datasource and the links all have only english version
4. I am opening the page in `de-de` language and I can't see any of the links (the component itself is visible - I can see div.component.link-list in the source)
5. The problem above does not happen on carousel for example (so I have slides in English and see them all in German version).

---

I had a similar issue in SXA 1.2 and I digged into `LinkListRepository` which inherits from `ListRepository` where there is a `GetItem()` method. This method uses extension method `GetItemsWithVersion()` from `ItemExtensions` class. I think this might cause the problem with language fallback - the items are just not returned if there is no version. Moreover in the extension method there is a following piece of code used:

```
i.Versions.GetVersions(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
```

and the items are visible in edit mode.

The questions from my side:

1. Is this correct behavior of a bug?
2. Is there any hidden mechanism to enable language fallback on list components?
3. If not, how can I override `LinkListRepository` to fix this problem? I cannot find it registered in the the `<services>` section so I could replace it with my own implementation?
   I have a custom Link List component and custom repository registered but apparently it gets overriden by original `LinkListRepository` being registered later on. This method worked in SXA 1.2.

---

**UPDATE**

I have managed to workaround this problem by moving my configurator class which creates an instance of `ILinkListRepository` to the end of the `<service>` section.

Which leaves me with question: Where on earth are you instantiating your class? Plus confirm please if this is expected or a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is this correct behavior of a bug?

This as a bug. This code simply does what it says. It will not work with language fallback which is not expected.

> 2. Is there any hidden mechanism to enable language fallback on list components?

Nope, you have to overwrite it or ask support for a hotfix.

> 3. I cannot find it registered in the  section so I could replace it with my own implementation

1. In this config `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.IoC.config` you will find configurator node
2. This class `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.IoC.ServiceCollection.RegisterMvcControllersIoC` does something like `serviceCollection.AddMvcControllers("namespace");`
3. Somewhere inside `AddMvcControllers` you will find:

```
var repositories = GetTypesImplementing<IControllerRepository>(assemblies)
                .Where(repo => repo.Name.EndsWith("Repository", StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

(later all of them are registered automatically)

This does the whole job. Notice that every repository inherits from `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.IoC.IControllerRepository`

I don't have exact steps on how to overwrite it.

Comment: For the record - I have created a Configurator class where I am registering my own implementation of `LinkListRepository` where the problem is fixed (I am overriding `GetItems()` method). It didn't work because I have been registering my implementation before `RegisterMvcControllersIoC` class

Comment: @SzymonKuzniak You should not register new service but replace the existing one. In such a case, you don't need to bother about the order. Take a look for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590769/replace-service-registration-in-asp-net-core-built-in-di-container