# The type or namespace name "IocProcessor"could not be found In SXA custom component

Tags: sxa

I am trying to register service with IoC Processor in SXA custom component But i have face error "the type or namespace name "IocProcessor"could not be found"

[image]

What should i go for resolved error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *can* register the dependencies with config patch files like [Alan Płócieniak](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/16/alan-p%c5%82%c3%b3cieniak) mentioned, you can also achieve this through a `configurator` class which would be closer to what you have in your example:

```
public class RegisterVoteService : IServicesConfigurator    
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IVoteRepository, VoteRepository>();
        }
}
```

Then you register your configurator with a patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <configurator type="MyNamespace.RegisterVoteService, MyAssembly" />
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now you can add more registrations to that configurator class as you need it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the [documentation article](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/walkthrough--building-a-simple-rendering.html) (one that you probably used) is outdated because `IocProcessor` no longer exists (since 1.7 I believe).

For **Controllers** and **Repositories** you could use a trick from SXA. I described it [**here**](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/sxa-language-fallback-in-list-components/16775#16775)

For other services please use a new approach and register it in configuration, example below.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <register serviceType="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Media.Services.IMediaItemService, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Media" implementationType="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Media.Services.MediaItemService, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Media" lifetime="Singleton"/>
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

More about DI in Sitecore [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/dependency-injection.html)